# Complete.cases used on list of data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove all the NA values from a list of data frames. The only way I have got it to work is by cleaning the data with complete.cases in a for loop. Is there another way of doing this with lapply as I had been trying for a while to no avail. Here is the code that works.

I start with

```
data_in  <- lapply (file_name,read.csv)
```

Then have:

```
clean_data <- list()  
for (i in seq_along(id)) {
   clean_data[[i]] <- data_in[[i]][complete.cases(data_in[[i]]), ]
}
```

But what I tried to get to work was using lapply all the way like this.

```
comp <- lapply(data_in, complete.cases)

clean_data <- lapply(data_in, data_in[[id]][comp,])
```

Which returns this error "Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list' "

What I'd like to know is some alternatives or if I was going about this right. And why didn't the last example not work?

Thank you so much for your time. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expected with

```
clean_data <- lapply(data_in, data_in[[id]][comp,])
```

The second parameter to `lapply` should be a proper function to which each member of the `data_in` list will be passed one at a time. Your expression `data_in[[id]][comp,]` is not a function. I'm not sure where you expected `id` to come from, but `lapply` does not create magic variables for you like that. Also, at this point `comp` is now a list itself of indices. You are making no attempt to iterate over this list in sync with your `data_in` list. If you wanted to do it in two separate steps, a more appropriate approach would be

```
comp <- lapply(data_in, complete.cases)
clean_data <- Map(function(d,c) {d[c,]}, data_in, comp)
```

Here we use `Map` to iterate over the `data_in` and `comp` lists simultaneously. They each get passed in to the function as a parameter and we can do the proper extraction that way. Otherwise, if we wanted to do it in one step, we could do

```
clean_data <- lapply(data_in, function(x) x[complete.cases(x),])
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that id is a vector that refers to all the segments in the list so like 1:10 or something like that. I'm sure that was a horrible way of describing id... I see your point with my problem with lapply.

Comment: I have never used the map function or heard of it and will now dig in to this. Thank you all for your help. It is very much appreciated. Will study your comments more but I think you've answered all my questions.

Answer (score 3):

welcome to SO, please provide some working code next time

here is how i would do it with `na.omit` (since `complete.cases` only returns a logical)

```
(dat.l <- list(dat1 = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c(1, NA)),
              dat2 = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(1, NA, 3))))

# $dat1
#   x  y
# 1 1  1
# 2 2 NA
# 
# $dat2
#   x  y
# 1 1  1
# 2 2 NA
# 3 3  3

Map(na.omit, dat.l)

# $dat1
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 
# $dat2
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the below?

```
> lst
$a
   a
1  1
2  2
3 NA
4  3
5  4

$b
   b
1  1
2 NA
3  2
4  3
5  4

$d
   d  e
1 NA  1
2 NA  2
3  3  3
4  4 NA
5  5 NA

> f <- function(x) x[complete.cases(x),]
> lapply(lst, f)
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4

$d
  d e
3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name[complete.cases(file_name), ]
```

complete.cases() returns only a logical value. This should do the job and returns only the rows with no NA values.